# Pagination through Sql query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, gridview

I am developing an application in which am using grid view. I want to use pagination for that grid view by using sql query.

I want to display records with the help of `pagesize` and `pageindex`.

How can I do this with sql query?

Comment: Thanks for the solution.its working but now if i have 20 records and accordingly your solution it gives result but next page index is vanish so what can i do for this?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use pagination for that grid view by using sql query.
>
> I want to display records with the help of pagesize and pageindex.

With two parameters passed to the sql query `@pageindex` and `@pagesize`, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to do pagination. Something like the following:

```
;With CTEForPagination AS  
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SomeFieldToOrderBy) AS RowNum,  * 
   FROM YourTableReference
)
SELECT *   
FROM CTEForPagination
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN ((@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize + 1)
    AND (@PageIndex * @PageSize)
ORDER BY AnotherFieldToOrderBy
--This is just an example
```

### [Example Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/84211/pagination-through-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks for the solution.its working but now if i have 20 records and accordingly your solution it gives result but next page index is vanish so what can i do for this?

Comment: @user1661897 - Your application should manage the value of the `@pageIndex` parameter, so that each click of the next button, it should be incremented the same as the prev. You should also take care of the first and the last pages

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH EmpOrdered AS
(   
SELECT
Lastname,
ROW_NUMBER() Over (ORDER BY Lastname) AS rownum  
FROM Employees
)
SELECT e.*
FROM Employees e
INNER JOIN EmpOrdered ON e.Lastname = EmpOrdered.Lastname
WHERE EmpOrdered.rownum BETWEEN 1000 AND 1050
ORDER BY EmpOrdered.rownum ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUserByPaging
(
    @PageSize int,
    @PageIndex int
)
AS
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
declare 
    @StartRow int,
    @EndRow int

    if(@PageIndex < 1)
      Set @PageIndex = 1

    Set @StartRow = (@PageSize * (@PageIndex - 1)) + 1
    Set @EndRow = @PageSize * @PageIndex


SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT
       ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order By u.UserID) RowNumber,
       u.UserID,
       u.UserName
    FROM 
        Users u) u
    WHERE 
        ((u.RowNumber Between @StartRow AND @EndRow))
```